# Terraform Google cloud service account issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to create a GKE Cluster through Terraform. Facing an issue w.r.t service accounts. In our enterprise, service accounts to be used by Terraform are created in a project **svc-accnts** which resides in a folder named prod.

I'm trying to create the GKE cluster in a different folder which is Dev and the project name is **apigw**. Thro Terraform, when I use a service account with the necessary permissions reside in the project apigw, it works fine.

But when I try to use a service account with the same permissions where the service account resides in a different folder, getting this error

`Error: googleapi: Error 403: Kubernetes Engine API has not been used in project 8075178406 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/container.googleapis.com/overview?project=8075178406 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.`

where 8075178406 is the project number of **svc-accnts**

Why does it try to enable the API in **svc-accnts** when the GKE cluster is created in **apigw**. Are service accounts not meant to used across folders?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Service Accounts are owned by one Project but may be used by any. This happens in every project with Google-managed Service Accounts. The Service Account must be explicitly added to other Projects or resources through the resource's IAM bindings though.

Comment: Since the service account resides on the project under the prod folder - "svc-accnts", and the service account with the roles is applied on the DEV folder whose child is the "apigw" project, the service account with the permissions are automatically applied on the "apigw" project through inheritance. So I guess this satisfies the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue and happens through gcloud cli as well.

https://issuetracker.google.com/180053712

The workaround is to enable the Kubernetes Engine API on the project(svc-accnts) and it works fine. I was hesitant to do that as I thought this might create the resources in the project.

Answer (score 0):

The error you provide is not about permissions of the service account. Maybe you did not change the project in the provider? Remember, you can have multiple providers of the same type (google) that point to different projects. Some code example would provide more information.

See:

- https://medium.com/scalereal/how-to-use-multiple-aws-providers-in-a-terraform-project-672da074c3eb (this is for AWS, but same idea)
- https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/configuration

Comment: The projects are not applied on the providers, instead it is applied individually at the resources level. The project id is taken as a variable as an .auto.tfvars file and passed to individual resources through modules. All of the resources are properly set with the project id which is of the project apigw.